# How to map a single field inside a composite key as Primary key of another entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a composite key and The employee table has a one to many relationships with the address table.

```
@Embeddable
class EmployeeDetails {
    @Column(name="empid")
    Long empId;
    @Column(name="empdept")
    String empDept;
}

@Entity
class Employee {

    @EmbeddedId
    EmployeeDetails empDetails;

    @OneToOne (mappedBy = "employee")
    Address address;
}

@Entity
class Address {
    String permanentAddrs;
    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "empId", referencedcolumnname = "empDetails.empid")
    Employee employee;
}
```

What i want to do is make empId of `EmployeeDetails` as a primaryKey in `Address` entity.
But when i do above mapping i am getting following exception:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: empDetails.empid in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(employee) and its related supertables and secondary tables

Is the above mapping correct?

Comment: referencedcolumnname = "empid"

Answer (score -1):

@Shikhar: before going deep into the exception, there looks a big flaw in the design you are trying to impement.

**design looks to be a faulty one, why ?**

1. you created 1:M relation between Employee and address and in address table 
   you are trying to use empId as a primary Key.
   This is totally wrong.
2. what you are trying to achieve is, you want to use one of the column of composite key (i.e empId) as the FK in the Address table.
   This looks logically wrong.

Best of luck.

Comment: the thing is the question which I have asked is a simplified version of an ongoing application.So, I can't change the design of the database i am not allowed to do that.
Apart from this now can you suggest something better.

Comment: @ShikharChaudhary you will find lot of difficulties in implementing this design using Hibernate, you can go for mybatis instead or spring jdbc.